How can we have zero voltage on the ECG when the atria and ventricles are never the same charge at the same time?
Electrocardiography is based on the potential difference between two electrodes. The ST segment represents the period of time where the ventricles are completely depolarized, hence we get zero potential on the ECG. However, while the ventricles are depolarized, that is, they are negative (the outside of the cells), the atria are not depolarized, right?
So, my confusion rests with the fact that the electrodes, aren't they measuring any potential difference between the atria and the ventricles? How can we still have zero voltage because the heart is never FULLY the same charge, I mean the atria and the ventricles are never fully positive nor negative at the SAME TIME, or am I wrong?
For example, if we consider lead I since it measures in the vertical plane. At the end of the P wave, the atria are depolarized and at plateau until it repolarizes, during that time, however, the ventricles are polarized (positive outside the cell). So, mustn't there be a potential difference between the atria and the ventricles in lead I? So the PR segment should not be at 0 voltage, right?
Thanks!!

Are you thinking of the heart as a source of constant energy like a wall socket has? You put sensors in the two slots of a wall socket and you will always see a voltage differential. But you won't see the same from the heart.

The electrodes do not measure electrical potential difference between the atria and ventricles; they measure it between the electrodes. Potential difference is relative, so the isoelectric line does not represent an absolute zero, but rather no net potential difference in the direction of that lead.
